# state return by useReducer doesn't change when init value change

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

`dishState` return by `useReducer` doesn't change even though `initDishState` change. Is it caused by asynchronous process which makes the variable mutated somewhere ?

```
export default function DishModal({
  type,
  itemCode,
  modalRef,
  initDishState,
  addedOrderState,
}: DishModalType): JSX.Element {
  const { menuInfo } = useContext(MenuContext);
  const menuDetailData = menuInfo.menu_detail;
  const itemInfo = menuDetailData[itemCode];
  const [dishState, DishDispatch] = useReducer(dishReducer, initDishState);
  console.log("initDishState", initDishState);
  console.log("dishState", dishState);
```

The code when I call `DishModal` is

```
export default function Cart({ cartState }: CartType): JSX.Element {
  const { menuInfo } = useContext(MenuContext);
  const menuDetail: IPayload = menuInfo.menu_detail;
  const ListOfDish = Object.entries(cartState).map(
    ([dishKey, dishValue], orderIdx) => {
      const dishState: IPayload[] = dishValue.state;
      const dishInit: IPayload = dishValue.init;
      const [, itemCode] = JSON.parse(dishKey);
      const dishInfo = menuDetail[itemCode];
      if (!dishInfo) return null; // avoid invalid data caused by backend
      return (
        <Dish
          key={orderIdx}
          dishKey={dishKey}
          dishInfo={dishInfo}
          dishState={dishState}
          dishInit={dishInit}
        />
      );
    }
  );
  return (
    <div id="cart">
      <div className="clearfix">
        <Link to="/" type="button" className="btn-close"></Link>
      </div>
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      {ListOfDish}
    </div>
  );
}

function Dish({ dishKey, dishInfo, dishState, dishInit }: DishType) {
  const { menuInfo } = useContext(MenuContext);
  const cartDispatch = useContext(CartDispatchContext);
  const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const menuDetailData: IPayload = menuInfo.menu_detail;
  const dishQuantity = dishState.length;
  const compactState = summarizeDishState(dishState);

  const handleModal = () => {
    if (modalRef.current) {
      const modalController = Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modalRef.current);
      modalController.show();
    }
  };

  const ListOfSelectedOption = Object.entries(compactState).map(
    ([optionCode, optionQuantity]) => {
      const optionInfo = menuDetailData[optionCode];
      const optionName = attrLang(optionInfo, "lang");
      return <li key={optionCode}>{`${optionName} (${optionQuantity})`}</li>;
    }
  );

  return (
    <div className="card mb-3">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <img
            src={imgFullPath(dishInfo.img)}
            className="img-fluid rounded-start"
            alt="..."
          ></img>
        </div>
        <div className="col d-flex flex-column">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5>{attrLang(dishInfo, "lang")}</h5>
            <ul>{ListOfSelectedOption}</ul>
          </div>
          <div className="card-footer dish-price">
            <strong>{dishInfo.price}</strong>円(税込み
            <strong>{Math.round(dishInfo.price * 1.1) || undefined}</strong>円)
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleModal}>
            edit
          </button>
          <DishQuantitySelector
            dishKey={dishKey}
            addedState={dishInit}
            quantity={dishQuantity}
            dispatch={cartDispatch}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <DishModal
        type={"replace"}
        itemCode={dishInfo.poscd}
        modalRef={modalRef}
        initDishState={dishState}
        addedOrderState={dishInit}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current value of a reducer isn't supposed to change when the initial value changes. That is why it is called the **initial** value.

`useReducer` returns a dispatcher (which I've renamed here because convention reserves variables starting with a Capital Letter for constructor functions (and components in React)).

```
const [dishState, dishDispatch] = useReducer(dishReducer, initDishState);
```

To change the values in the reducer you need to dispatch an action:

```
dishDispatch({type: 'change', payload: 'foo'});
```

---

If you want to use values from props, then you should probably be using the props **directly** and not involving a reducer.